Layed self-leveling compound in upstairs subfloor but subfloor started squeaking
I hired a contractor to lay new engineered wood floors in my 45 year old townhouse because there were initially a lot of squeaks in the old flooring. Once they ripped up the old floors, I made sure to tell them to nail/screw down the subfloors once more and make sure it's level before putting on the underlay and then the new floors.
When everything was completed it looked great and I was happy with it until 2 weeks later when we started to move furniture in, one spot of the flooring starting to squeak really badly and I can tell it's because of the subfloor. I can also feel the concrete between the flooring and the subfloor moving around between, so I assume the self-leveling compound is cracked in that spot. Very interesting thing is that the area around that specific pinpoint is still really solid.
I have limited information on how the contractor did the job, so maybe he took short cuts and didn't tighten the subfloor as he should have but my question is can I purchase one of those "squeaky floor kits" from Amazon to screw down the subfloor through my flooring and then just putty the nail hole? Or will that damage the self-leveling compound around it and make it squeak more?
Additional information:

Subfloor is 5/8" plywood
I know the "right fix" is to rip it up and identify the problem but I can't afford to do that and my contractor will not come back to do it for free as well. Looking for a budget friendly fix

I just really want to fix that squeak spot.... It's bothering me a lot... Thanks a lot everyone!

Your issue really is that you assumed that the squeak was from the anchoring of the subflooring.  You admitted the squeak was gone and you were happy.   Your question has many assumptions and started by you assuming that the subfloor needed to be nailed or screwed.  The only proper way to identify the cause of the squeak is with examination, but as you stated, you don't want to do that.  All that said , there is no way that we could know if a "squeaky floor kit" will work.  Best advice is try it and see.

I just wanted to check if the self leveling concrete will get worse and crack more if I put a screw through it. I know for a fact it's the subfloor that is up because you can even hear the squeak from downstairs

@RMDman  I agree. At this point, try it and see.  That's what us old timers did before there was the internet...

How thick is the leveling concrete?

@ Jason, Because you can hear a squeak, either upstairs or downstairs does not identify what exactly is causing the squeak.  Also suppose the leveling compound is cracked, if putting a screw through it cures the problem, what is your worry?  If it doesn't what have you lost?

Trying out the squeaky floor kits" from Amazon  would not harm, but it might not help
